# Proof of the Sum of Square Roots

Tags: proof-writing

I have a question about a problem I encountered:

$\exists$ a,b $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{R}$+ such that $\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$

Any tips for going about solving this?

I tried:

$\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$

$a+b=a+b$

I have a feeling this isn't a legal operation...

Comment: $(X+Y)^2 = X^2 + Y^2 + 2 X Y$.

Comment: $\exists a>0,b>0$ with $\sqrt{a+b} = \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$? The problem is there is no such $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 5):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Suppose such $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^+$ do exist, then square both sides of $\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$.

Answer (score 2):

i think you just need to find the value of $a$ and $b$ so that the conditions are met
but we know that only $a=0$ or $b=0$ such that conditions met
is $0\in\mathbb{R^+}$? if yes then the statement is true

Comment: $\sqrt{2+2} = 2 \neq 2\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: ahh,i'm sorry haha

Comment: i think the conditions only met when $a=b=0$ isn't it?

Comment: @A Ricko Maulidar No, the conditions are met if, and only if, $a=0 \vee b=0$. But notice that the OP wants solutions in $\mathbb{R}^+$, so there are none.

Comment: yes,that's what i mean haha :p i'm sorry :) thankyou for the correction :)

Comment: Thanks A Ricko, but yea it needs to be positive. I do not believe there is such solution.

Comment: you're welcome :)